# Junk mail doesn't get automatically deleted

Tags: macos, mail.app, spam, pop

This is happening with Mail.app 6.6 on OS X 10.8.5, but has been going on for a few OS X versions.

In Mail.app, my account settings specify to delete junk mail after one day.  Except it never gets deleted.  I can set it to delete on quitting mail, but that still doesn't work.  I have to delete everything in the junk mail folder manually.  Items are placed in the Junk folder that are identified as junk, but they are never deleted automatically.

The accounts in question (I have the same issue in all of them) are POP3.  I tried rebuilding the mailboxes, to no avail. None of the affected mailboxes are gmail, though I do have a gmail account I look at through Mail.app.

I asked this on the Apple discussion forums, but no answer there. can anyone here make any suggestions?

From the online Help for Mail.app:
[image]

This is exactly what I've set to anything *other* than never, but messages in the junk mailbox doesn't ever get automatically deleted.

Comment: I found a similar thread about this, several years old, here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/622783?start=15&tstart=0  I'm going to check out the suggestions there.

Comment: Well, the directory structure has changed since the above thread was created.  I can find many plist and Envelope Index type files scattered through out, but I'm not going to touch them since I don't know what I'm doing.  I haven't seen any that are obviously associated with "junk".  Since I'm also having trouble with the junk mail filter learning what _is_ junk, those would be nice to find.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it got a negative vote from you. I would still strongly suggest to convert to the IMAP mail system even if there is no documented case of Junk mail not working in your POP3. Good luck.

Comment: what is "Remove copy from server after retrieving a message" set to under the account's Advanced tab?

Comment: @dwightk It's checked, and set to "immediately". See also my Apple discussion posting: https://discussions.apple.com/message/24274772#24274772  There are some screen shots there (but not, alas, from the Advanced tab).